# Sum of $1/f_{2^k}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, fibonacci-numbers

Let $\left(f_n\right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be the Fibbonacci sequence. I've seen that:
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{f_{2^n}}=\frac{7-\sqrt{5}}{2}
$$
I wonder how we can prove this result. Any hint ?